# await of generator completing in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I have code in component,
I need to get updated authorizedError value in function, but i get old value authorized error

// login component

```
const authorizedError = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.authorizedError);

const onSignInPress = useCallback(async () => {
            await dispatch(userActions.postLoginUser({username: email, password}));
  if (authorizedError) {
            setNotificationErrors(['Wrong login or password'])
            showNotification();
        }

    }, [authorizedError, validate, email, password]);
```

// postLoginUserSaga.js

```
export default function* postLoginUserSaga({
  payload,
}: PayloadAction<UserCredentialsPayload>) {
  try {
    yield put(setSignInError(false));
    const {
      data: {
        payload: { access_token },
        status,
      },
    } = yield transport.post(URLS.postLoginUserURL, payload);
    if (status !== "Ok") {
      throw new Error(status);
    }
    yield setItemAsync(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, access_token);
    yield put(setSignIn(true));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("User login failed", error);
    yield put(setSignInError(true));
  }
}
```

// sagaRoot file

```
export default function* userRootSaga() {
  yield all([
    checkAuthSaga(),
    takeEvery(actions.postLoginUser, postLoginUserSaga),
    takeEvery(actions.postRegistrationUser, postRegistrationUserSaga),
    takeEvery(actions.getProfileData, getProfileDataSaga),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Redux actions don't return a promise, you can't use them like this.

If you want to use the promise API you can use the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware which supports it.

If you want to use sagas you can add a callback action property instead.

```
// in component callback
dispatch(userActions.postLoginUser({username: email, password, callback: (authorizedError) => {
  if (authorizedError) {
    setNotificationErrors(['Wrong login or password'])
    showNotification();
  }
}));

// in saga
try {
  ...
  action.callback();
} catch (err) {
  action.callback(err);
}
```

Although that has its own [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69267981/callback-in-redux-redux-saga-is-an-anti-pattern).

Usually you communicate from sagas back to components by changing the redux state, so you can e.g. have a state for redux `error`, and based on that field show the error message or show different component if the login was succesful.